# Joomla: How can we change default url redirect to custom Form pages?

Tags: joomla2.5

Within Joomla 2.5.6 core login module their are three links under the login text boxes.

```
Forgot your password?
Forgot your username?
Don't have an account?
```

If a user clicks on "Create an account" it redirects then to the Joomla default registration form `mysite/index.php/en/joomla/joomla-components/registration-form?view=reset`

how can we change this to redirect to custom Forms page?

```
mysite/index.php/en/forgot-password
mysite/index.php/en/forgot-username
mysite/index.php/en/create-account
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do it.

1. You can assign a menu item for each link.
   Just create menus for each type like login,forgot password etc.

   [image]
2. Or another way is to do with `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 1):

If I am not getting you wrong than this will help you.
You can override the default layout of login module [Read More](http://www.ostraining.com/blog/joomla/alternative-layouts-for-modules/)

Copy `modules/mod_login/tmpl/default.php` and paste this to `/templates/activetemplate/html/mod_login`.And change the below code

```
<ul>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_users&view=reset'); ?>">
            <?php echo JText::_('MOD_LOGIN_FORGOT_YOUR_PASSWORD'); ?></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_users&view=remind'); ?>">
            <?php echo JText::_('MOD_LOGIN_FORGOT_YOUR_USERNAME'); ?></a>
        </li>
        <?php
        $usersConfig = JComponentHelper::getParams('com_users');
        if ($usersConfig->get('allowUserRegistration')) : ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_users&view=registration'); ?>">
                <?php echo JText::_('MOD_LOGIN_REGISTER'); ?></a>
        </li>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </ul>
```

And set the layout in login module.